# MongoDB: how can I pull an entire object from an object array that matches the Objectid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, axios

My question is, how I can pull a team object in `teams` that matches the unique `_id` of a team(in `teams` array).
Here is what I have tried, however, the problem is that all entries in `teams` get deleted, instead of only the object that matches the team `_id`.

```js
router.put("/delete/team/:id/:org", (req, res) => {
  const orgid = req.params.org;
  const _id = req.params.id;

  Organization.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: orgid,
    },
    {
      $pull: {
        teams: { _id: _id },
      },
    },
    { multi: true }
  )
    .then((organization) => {
      res.status(200).json(organization);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json(err);
    });
});
```

Each Organization in OrganizationSchema has a unique `_id`.
Also, each team(object) in `teams` array has a unique `_id`.

```js
const OrganizationSchema = new Schema({
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  register_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  teams: [
    {
      sport: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
      },
      access_code: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
      },
      admin: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
      events: [
        {
          date_time: {
            type: Date,
            offset: true,
          },
          opponent: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          home_away: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
          },
          expected_attendance: {
            type: Number,
          },
          people_attending: [
            { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
          ],
          amenities: [String],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: Likely reason: The `req.params.id` is a string, whereas the automatically assigned `_id` by MongoDB is a binary object. So, convert your string to an object: `teams: { _id: ObjectId(_id) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason for the output you are getting is, because you are matching an ObjectId with a string.

You need to convert your string to an object.

You can do this by adding,

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
```

And then,

```
 $pull: {
        teams: { _id: new ObjectID(_id) },
      },
```